# How to send and array in $http.delete

Tags: angularjs, http, meanjs

I want to delete the tag created using http post. here is the code that i have tried.

```
$http({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: '/api/tags',
    data: [vm.tags.name]
}).success(function(data) {
    console.log('Gets DELETED');
    vm.tags.name = data;
}).error(function(data) {
    console.log('Does not get DELETED');
});
```

However this didn't work and it only sends an array with [null]. So is there something i don't see or understand here. I mean, if the POST works it should work the same way with DELETE, right? By the way it shows the log "Gets DELETED" but didn't do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution! In my case HTTP 1.1 was able to send the body, but the header was not able so use the content of JSON. So, by adding `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}` to the data: field of the `$http.delete` it worked and the array got send.

I hope this helps someone.

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request), if you send something in the body of DELETE is ignored.

You should send in the path like this:

```
current/path?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4
```

It's like the GET method, you are not allowed to send anything in the body.

**UPDATE**

If you make a request with the URL parameters in the example, you will receive a object like this:

```
{ id : [1, 2, 3, 4] }
```

Comment: but the article states that HTTP 1.1 allows this?

Comment: ok, but lets assume that is the problem, how can i send the array in the path i tried: 'api/tags/' + [ myarray ]

Comment: I don't think so, if you take a look in the [HTTP document for delete](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7) you will see that only parameters mentioned is in the URI.

Comment: If you want to receive a array of IDs for example, you can send multiple strings in the URL like in the example, I updated with a example of the final object